# Why do these two implementations of expmod differ for large values?

Tags: python, algorithm

I've written out a couple of functions for doing [`expmod`](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~neto/code/fastexp.scm), that is, `(x ** y) % n`. These are both standard functions, I've checked and re-checked both but can't find any silly errors.

Here's the recursive one:

```
def expmod(x,y,m):
    if y == 0: return 1
    if y % 2 == 0:
        return square(expmod(x,y/2,m)) % m # def square(x): return x*x
    else:
        return (x * expmod(x,y-1,m)) % m
```

...and here's the non-recursive one:

```
def non_recursive_expmod(x,y,m):
    x = x % m
    y = y % m
    result = 1
    while y > 0:
        if(y%2 == 1):
            result = (result * x) % m
        x = (x*x) % m
        y = y/2
    return result
```

They agree for small values:

```
>>> expmod(123,456,789) - non_recursive_expmod(123,456,789)
0
```

...but don't for larger ones:

```
>>> expmod(24354321,5735275,654) - non_recursive_expmod(24354321,5735275,654)
-396L
```

What's going on?

Comment: There is pow() function in python. Third parameter can be mod.

Comment: `TypeError: pow expected 2 arguments, got 3`

Comment: @TomMedley: you probably did a star-import from math (from math import *), which replaced the builtin 3-argument pow with the math library's pow, which only has 2.

Comment: Fair enough. It still doesn't answer the question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `non_recursive_expmod` has some suspicious steps in it: Remove the `%m` for `x` and `y` at the beginning. Both are not needed.

Additionally make sure that the division of `y` is an integer division by using `y = y // 2`.

In total the function should look like this:

```
def non_recursive_expmod(x, y, m):
    result = 1
    while y > 0:
        if y % 2 == 1:
            result = (result * x) % m
        x = (x * x) % m
        y = y // 2
    return result
```

Comment: Making those changes breaks it completely! This algorithm is correct, if you work through it with small values it's clear it's doing the right thing.

Comment: That has fixed it, thanks! Add it to your answer so I can accept.

Comment: @Tom Medley You can leave the `x=x%m` in there but the `y` one is breaking it for sure.

Comment: @Michael J. Barber You are right about that one. Changed it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Non recursive does not decrease y in case it is odd, and even part needs else in case y == 1

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say here.